# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable on kubectl apply -f k8s

Tags: kubernetes

express-cluster-ip-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: express-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: server
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

express-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: express-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: express
          image: simonjames/react-node-docker-kubernetes-app-express
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: redis-cluster-ip-service
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: '6379'
            - name: PGUSER
              value: postgres
            - name: PGHOST
              value: postgres-cluster-ip-service
            - name: PGPORT
              value: '5432'
            - name: PGDATABASE
              value: postgres
            - name: PGPASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgpassword
                  key: PGPASSWORD
```

react-cluster-ip-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  react-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: web
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

react-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: react-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: react
          image: simonjames/react-node-docker-kubernetes-app-react
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

ingres-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: react-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: express-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
```

I am getting a 503 error when I browse the url mapped to my minikube. What may be causing this? Is there any issue with the config. It ran fine when I used docker-compose.yaml. I am using similar configs, so what is the issue here?

Comment: What vm driver for minikube are you using? How do you expose this in minikube?

Comment: I am using virtual box

Comment: And you are receiving 503 on both paths?

Answer (score 0):

A **503 Service Unavailable Error** is an [`HTTP response status code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) indicating that a server is *temporarily* unable to handle the request. This may be due to the server being overloaded or down for maintenance.

I performed a test with your deployment yamls  but used a different images since I don`t have access to the one that you mention and it all works fine for me. Ingress and services are correctly sending traffic to appropriate pods. If I remove one once of the services I get exact the same error when trying to reach it.

This indicates that this is `server connectivity issue` and traffic  cannot reach your pods due to some configuration, port mismatch or that somewhere in the chain server is down or unreachable.

I suggest you to first check your connectivity with different images and confirm the same results as mine. As second check you may want to look into `nginx controller pod`:

```
kubectl logs -n <namespace> <Ingress_nginx_controller_pod_name>
```